# Cant make regex work to remove the first white space character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following div:

```
<div data-test="([1] Hello World), ([2] Foo Bar)"></div>
```

Now what I am trying to do is to find the cleanest way to break the string into the following pieces:

**array ["1", "Hello World", "2", "Foo Bar"];**

How can I achieve this the proper and fast way?

I managed to get close but my solution seems somewhat ugly and doesnt work as expected.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    data = el.getAttribute('data-test');
    list = data.replace(/[([,]/g, '').split(/[\]\)]/);

for(str of list) {
    str = str.trim();
}
```

I still get the spaces at the start of each string. I dont really want to use trim or anything similar. I tried to add a whitespace character to my regex s/ but that was a bad idea too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below function should work.

```
function strToArr(str) {
    var arr = [];
    var parts = str.split(', ');
    parts.forEach(part => {
        var digit = part.match(/(\d+)/g)[0];
        var string = part.match(/(\b[a-zA-Z\s]+)/g)[0];
        arr.push(digit, string);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: See my example please.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = '([1] Hello World), ([2] Foo Bar)';

var textReplaced = text.replace(/\(\[([^\]])\]\s([^)]+)\)/g, '$1, $2');

var array = textReplaced.split(', ');

console.log(array);
```

Without any cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
list = data.replace(/^\(\[|\)$/g, '').split(/\] |\), \(\[|\] /);
```

Two steps:

1. remove the heading "(["and tailing ")"
2. split the string into the parts you want with the delimiter symbols

Suppose the format of the string is fixed.